# Image_tag First Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Carrierwave use, I would like to show the first picture of a publication.

Try the following:

```
 <% @autos.each do |auto| %>

       <tr class="list">

         <td><%= image_tag auto.fotos.first.to_s , size: "50x50" %></td>
         <td><%= auto.ciudad %></td>
         <td><%= auto.marca %></td>
         <td><%= auto.modelo %></td>
         <td><%= auto.version %></td>
         <td><%= auto.año %></td>
         <td><%= auto.hp %></td>
         <td><%= auto.km %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Show', auto %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_auto_path(auto) %></td>
         <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', auto, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are?' }%></td>

       </tr>

     <% end %>
```

[image]

This makes it look like hexadecimal, not illustrated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `image_tag` an image URL. Instead of calling `to_s` on the model, you need to call `url` on the uploader attribute.

```
auto.fotos.first.foto.url
```

Comment: Rails says, undefined method `url' for #<Foto:0x007f636e697980> :( 

Hablas español?

Comment: class Foto < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :auto
  mount_uploader :foto, FotoUploader

 
end

Comment: Updated the answer above. You need to call `url` on the uploader attribute. In your case you have a `Foto` model and a `foto` uploader so you need `fotos.first.foto.url`

Comment: sorry, as I call url on the uploader attribute?, rails says undefined method `foto' for nil:NilClass

Comment: @MiguelAbdonHollstein That means that the `auto` does not have any `Foto` records in its `fotos` collection

Comment: sorry, no picture had a car. Resolved Question, thank you very much Carlos Ramirez.